# How to add 1 to max value?

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and need some help. Trying to automate a worksheet I use frequently. I have figured out how to add a row towards the bottom of the sheet with:

```
MaxRow = Application.Match(Application.Max(Range("N:N")), Range("N:N"), 0)
        Cells(MaxRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
```

but can't figure out how to increase the yellow highlighted cell by 1 from the value above. I'll be adding multiple line items, so it needs to be consecutive working top to bottom.

[image: Summary Sheet]

I also need to copy the sheet at the end of the workbook and rename it with the newly added item number.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Cells(MaxRow + 1, 1).Value` = `Cells(maxRow,1).Value + 1`? Or use `Range.AutoFill`.

Comment: Thanks this worked, how would i copy the formulas from above to the newly added row?

Comment: Copy/paste formulas? See related questions here on SO, or use the macro recorder to get you started.

Comment: @BrandonJenkins `Rows(MaxRow).Copy Destination:=Rows(MaxRow+1)`?  Or, use `FillDown`?

Comment: You might be able to use FillDown to generate the new row entirely instead of `insert`ing a new row